# How to stop CLLocation manager updating IMMEDIATELY

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I am having `ClLocationManager` code in my `viewWillAppear`. I the same view controller I am having a button which opens a web view. I want to stop location manager IMMEDIATELY, when user taps on button. I am using `[locationManager stopUpdating]` and `locationManager.delegate = nil`. From `CLLOCATION` delegate method I open `MFMailComposer` sheet.

**Problem:** Even after clicking on button (which is opening web view), my `MailComposerCode` executes. How to stop it?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [self setUpProgressBar];

    if (webViewButtonClicked == YES)//when user came bck from web view pick up latest coordinates
    {
        webViewButtonClicked = NO;
        [self getLocationCoordinates];
    }
    else//get latest coordinates from CLLocation manger
    {
        if (!locationManager) {
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        }
        if (!self.geocoder) {
            self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        }

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        // This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will
        // attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        // When "tracking" the user, the distance filter can be used to control the frequency with which location measurements
        // are delivered by the manager. If the change in distance is less than the filter, a location will not be delivered.
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        // Once configured, the location manager must be "started".
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (IBAction)goToWEBVIEW
{
    NSLog(@"setting to YES");

    webViewButtonClicked = YES;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;

    aWebViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController aWebViewController animated:NO];
}
```

`CLLocationManager` delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    if (webViewButtonClicked==NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"1234");
        if (!self.sender) {
            [self.gpsActivityindicator stopAnimating];
            [self stopUpdatingLocation:@""];
            self.destinationForProgressView = .25;
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
            **[self openMailComposer];**
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see in `goToWebView` method I am having a flag `webViewButtonClicked = YES`, but delegate method is called before the user has tapped on web view button. So condition `if (webViewButtonClicked==NO)` becomes `true`? How can I stop this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)goToWEBVIEW
{
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 NSLog(@"setting to YES");

webViewButtonClicked = YES;
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = nil;

aWebViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController aWebViewController animated:NO];}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i have already tried that even i have used perform selector after delay, basically the order of commands doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
 [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
if (webViewButtonClicked==NO)
{
    NSLog(@"1234");
    if (!self.sender) {
        [self.gpsActivityindicator stopAnimating];
        [self stopUpdatingLocation:@""];
        self.destinationForProgressView = .25;
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        **[self openMailComposer];**
    }
}
```

}